# MacBook Pro 13" 2020 Left Fan at full speed even when computer is switched off

Tags: macbook-pro

One day after a long storage time I switched on my MacBook Pro 13" 2020 (A2251) and the left fan was on at full blast all the time — **even with the machine switched off**. The fan (usually 8881 rpm) only switches off when the machine goes completely out of battery.

I tried SMC and PRAM reset to no avail, reinstalling the operating system didn't help, etc etc. I downloaded MacsFanControl but I can't reduce the speed or switch off the fan using the software (btw, right fan is ok, usually at 0 rpm—maybe to compensate—but can be controlled ok using MacsFanControl). The laptop just went out of warranty and I would like to avoid bringing it in for repair.

I am no expert but it feels like there must be some physical component (like a transistor) that has some issue. There was no water spillage whatsoever (not that I remember of at least), I just left the computer stored in a drawer inside its laptop case (protected from dust) for a few months while on parental leave. However, the computer was stored under a heavy pile of paper sheets (maybe 3-4 pounds). I'm unsure this could have caused the problem.

**Could a fan replacement help? I am not convinced of this option because the left fan is actually working, what is not working is the control of the fan speed.** Any input is welcome!!

Thanks in advance you all!

sil

Comment: Can you check [apple diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to see if it reports anything? My feeling is that the fan unit is broken. I'm not sure how easy it is to replace a fan in a 2020 MBP, but I've done it in a 2009 model which was fairly easy. A replacement fan was around 30 euros back then.

Comment: At the very least, an Apple Store will be able to confirm/identify the problem for free. Whether you pay for them to fix it, or do it yourself, is up to you.

Comment: Hi @SaaruLindestøkke, Apple diagnostics tells me "There may be an issue with the fan", and gives Reference code PPF003, and additional reference code PPF004

Comment: Well, that's pretty clear then. Going to the Apple Store for a replacement is definitely an option, but in my vicinity they are always trying to upsell hard. Last time I wanted a simple battery replacement to regain capacity. After a week long (free) diagnostic session they decided that replacing the motherboard would be better, but that's quite expensive, so I could just as well look at the newer models, etc.... I went to another repair shop, they swapped the battery in 30 minutes. Just a heads up.

Comment: Well this macbook is basically new and quite expensive (looking back, it's a bummer I didn't get extended coverage). I only used it for a little over 6 months, so I guess for me replacing the motherboard or getting a new one is not an option. I'll see what they suggest at the Apple Store and update you all here!

Answer (score 1):

Update: I went to the local Apple Store and the person who helped me was able to solve the issue by just disconnecting and reconnecting fans and battery (and free of charge!). He said the connectors were securely in place, so maybe by unplugging the battery something got reset in the circuit (something that had not been fixed by SMC/PRAM reset). Thanks you all